# How to read a file and insert some thing at the start and end of a file?

Tags: php, xml, file

I have a file name `$xml` in which my xml is saved. I want to read it and  want to insert:

```
$xml = <<<EOT
```

At the start of file and  `EOT;` at the end and then save it.

How can I do that?

By this line I get the content:

```
$contents = file_get_contents($xml);
```

By this I will save it again after changes:

```
$xml->save("write.xml");
```

Now how to insert 
`$xml = <<<EOT` this?

EOT is end of tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

Just get your file into an array with [`file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) then add your line to the start with [`array_unshift()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php) and with [`array_push()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) add your line to the end. Then simply save the file again with [`file_put_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php).

```
<?php

    $xml = "write.xml";
    $lines = file($xml, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
    array_unshift($lines, '$xml = <<<EOT');
    array_push($lines, 'EOT;');
    file_put_contents($xml, implode(PHP_EOL, $lines));

?>
```

Comment: @aesh To save the file again. And `implode()` to separate your lines with a new line, because I removed them when I read the file

Comment: can you tell why we use $xml = <<<EOT this?

Comment: @aesh You asked to add this ad the start of your file

Comment: yes  i asked because some one given me code in which inserting would give the result.. i dun know y we are inserting this.

Comment: @aesh What you use here is [`heredoc syntax`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)